# Symbol(rxSubscriber): undefined on IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am getting a blank page on IE11, however, works fine on chrome and Mozilla
Symbol(rxSubscriber)_m.hnzfdlt6ync: undefined on IE11!

```
Unhandled promise rejection ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 24 failed.
(timeout: [server]/bundles/24.bundle.js)
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      description: "",
      message: "Loading chunk 24 failed.
(timeout: [server]/bundles/24.bundle.js)",
      name: "ChunkLoadError",
      number: 0,
      request: "[server]/bundles/24.bundle.js",
      stack: "ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 24 failed.
(timeout: server/bundles/24.bundle.js)
   at __webpack_require__.oe ([server]/bundles/home.bundle.js:188:72)
   at run ([server]/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js:6575:13)
   at Anonymous function ([server]/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js:6592:30)
   at flush (server/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js:2575:9)",
      Symbol(rxSubscriber)_m.mdge73dfogj: undefined,
      type: "timeout"
   }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52038123/angular-6-problems-with-get-post-on-ie11-symbolrxsubscriber-is-undefined) it may help you :)